# Logistic Regression Negative Log Likelihood Loss Function

Tags: logistic-regression

Consider the following dataset:

[image]

We wish to fit a standard logistic regression model to this dataset.
(a) What will be the negative log likelihood loss function for this dataset.
(b) Is the iterative algorithm for determining the regression coefficients stable? How would you explain your answer.

Comment: If all you knew was that $X_1=0$, what would you predict? If all you knew was that $X_2=0$, what would you predict?

Comment: Welcome to the community. This seems like a class assignment. These should not be given to the community. If you have a question on an aspect of the assignment, that is fair to post. Also, posting what you have tried, your understanding, where you are having problems, is needed. Dave gave some hints so you may be able to move forward with the assignment.